# proj.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `pcap_open_offline'

Tags: c, pcap, undefined-reference

I'm trying to use pcap functions, but it giving me compiler error:

```
project.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `pcap_open_offline'
```

I have installed library and while compiling I give "-lpcap" at the and as it advised in many forums.

What can be wrong, please?

Comment: sorry,  *"-lpcap" at the end

Comment: do you provide a search path to libpcap.a? [Adding](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46920975/edit) your complie/linker command to the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what the arguments evoke into the linker.

I am supposing you are using Linux system with gcc, using ld as linker (note that this could change depending on the system and the linker used).

In such case, `-Lpath` tell the linker where to look for the libraries that you tell it that are needed to be linked with your program to create the final binary. For example `-L/usr/lib`.

when you type in for example:

```
# gcc -L/usr/lib -lcap my_program.c -o my_program
```

You are telling the linker to append `/usr/lib` to the list of paths to locate libraries, and to link the dynamic library "libcap.so" with your program.

Other modifiers for the path used to locate libraries is LD_LIBRAY_PATH (the name of this environment variable could change from one system to another, review the manual of your linker).

As you are using "-lcap" the error you get look to be related with the fact that no path is found where libcap.so exist. Locate that file into your system and pass the argument

`-L/path/to/the/directory/that/contain/libcap.so`

By the way, try to run this before any other thing and recompile:

```
# sudo ldconfig
```